# How to prove (un)decidability

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem, semi-decidability

Let's say we have a string **s** , a code size limit of **b** bytes and a time limit **t**, the question is then whether or not it is possible to construct an algorithm that prints the string within the time limit when a program is given **no input**.

**In other words - is this problem decidable or undecidable?**

I was thinking of reducing the Halt problem when it is given no input, but I'm a bit unsure of whether I should concider the byte size and time limit as input as well, or how I should conquer this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is decidable. You can enumerate the (finitely many) programs that use at most $b$ bytes.

For each such candidate program $P$, you can check whether $P$ is valid program (for any reasonable representation) and execute it for up to $t$ time steps. Eventually you either find a program that prints $s$ (and accept) or you run out of programs (and reject).

Comment: Thanks @Steven! Really appreciate your help and explanations!

Comment: But the fact that the program should be called with no input is irrelevant then?

Comment: Yes, as far as decidability is concerned. That assumption just makes things easier. For simplicity think of the the program as Turing machine. Even if you needed to guess the input, a Turing machine that runs for $t$ time steps can only observe the first $t$ tape cells so you only need to test one of the, finitely many, inputs of length at most $t$.

Comment: If the program is not a TM but you are using some other model of computation then things can get more annoying (since a program could access the input in random positions). However it is still true that a program can only observe at most $t$ positions of the input. What you could do is guess the observed values at the at the distinct positions probed by the algorithm (without actually needing to know/guess what the these positions are).

Comment: Okay, thanks! Makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, but let's say the program for example is written in Java - should I think about it as a TM anyway or should I then consider your last point about the program being able to access the input in random positions?

Comment: If you don't consider the case of non-empty inputs, it doesn't matter. If you insist that the program must be a Java program then you should consider my last point. However I think that this are more details than the question is asking about and that they might distract from the main point. Also if you go down this rabbit hole: how do you handle system calls? The main point it was trying get across is that you can enumerate all executions of all programs of length at most $b$ that last at most $t$ steps.

Comment: It's a theoretical question about computability, rather than a request to come up with concrete program. As far as computability is concerned, you can equivalently think of some Turing machine simulating a program written in your favorite language.

Comment: Okay, gotcha that the focus is not on specific programming languages, but more a theoretical question and that all programs' executions then can be enumerated where the length is b at most and the time frame is within t - regardless of programming language! Awesome!